# Ways to access elements of an array that's within an object

Tags: php, class, properties, reference

I'm trying to convert our existing codebase to a more correct approach. Our existing codebase is written in HTML with PHP and Javascript code inserted all over the place (not in an un-ordered fashion, but not like it should be).

So I'm converting our current codebase to make use of classes, so properties and methods are the way to proceed. But I have a problem. I (ideally) want to reference one of my class members by their names instead of by index. Let me put this in a code sample.

This is the form class:

```
class form {
    public $name;
    public $fields;

    {constructor goes here...}

    public function addField($type, $name, $hint = null, $info = null) {
        $this->fields[] = new field($type, $name, $hint, $info);
    }
}
```

And this is the field class (which the form class calls when creating a new form field):

```
class field {
    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $values;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->fields = null;
    }

    public function addValue($value, $minimum = null, $maximum = null, $step = 1) {
        $this->values[] = new value($value, $minimum, $maximum, $step);
    }
}
```

So my code would look like this:

```
$form = new form("form1");
$form->addField(NUMBER, "number1");
$form->fields[0]->addValue(25, 1, 250, 1);
```

It actually works, but it's not what I want in the end. I would like to call each field by its designated name so I could write this instead:

```
$form = new form("form1");
$form->addField(NUMBER, "number1");
$form->fields['number1']->addValue(25, 1, 250, 1);
```

Or even:

```
$form->addField(NUMBER, "number1")->addValue(25, 1, 250, 1);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of asking if it is possible, just try it.

Comment: Of course it is: `$this->fields[$name] = new field($type, $name, $hint, $info);`

Comment: Here is something i have learn with my own blood and sweat: **never write a form generator**. It never turns out well .. also, **your abstraction is leaking all over the place** !!

Comment: @ColeJohnson I always try a few solutions on my own before actually asking ;)

Comment: @AljoshaBre good answer! Although it's not complete, in the sense that I now have the array with keys, but I lost the index number, and I need both, so 0 can be 'check1', 1 can be 'textbox2' and so on... but hey, that was a great answer :)

Comment: @tereško it's the only possible way for us to deliver our clients with a solution for their needs. It's a multilevel management application with strict requirements on media type, accesibility and customisation, among others.

About the class being leaked all over the place, ok... classes are something I manage at the most simplistic level, so... if you have any suggestion, I'm all ears :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the fields are just an array within the form object. So instead of

```
 $this->fields[] = new field($type, $name, $hint, $info);
```

Could you just do this?

```
 $this->fields[$name] = new field($type, $name, $hint, $info);
```

Comment: Like I told **AljoshaBre**, it's a good answer, although my problem is I need both indexes, as what I'm looking for is a quick way to reference the array members. I can always do `echo $form->fields[27]->values[0]->value` but I would prefer a simpler way :)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to access the array both by field name and by numeric index? One way would be `array_keys($form->fields)` which gives you an numerically indexed array of field names. Then you can iterate over that list.

Comment: Yes, because I'm constructing the page renderer like a state machine. The `render()` method in my page class traverses all the page elements with a for loop and, depending on the element being analyzed, apply some conditions. That's why I want to preserve the index but, at the same time, have a quick way to locate the fields. I've found a temporary solution (I don't know how will it work in a multi-user environment) which is executing `define($name, count($this->fields) - 1);` to create a constant definition with the field name and the index of the newly created field. Works but still... hmm

Comment: Aren't constants created with DEFINE global in scope? That would create problems if you had two fields with the same name in different forms on one page. But perhaps that doesn't happen.

Comment: Correct... that's why I don't like it... it's just a temporary solution to show myself that's not the way to do things, but it works for now until I find a proper solution... I'll play with that `array_keys` function you hinted me at, as I think it will be a better approach :)

Comment: Solved it... it was like you and **AljoshaBre** said in the beginning. That 'simple' `$this->fields[$name] = new field($type, $name, $hint, $info);` solved the problem at the creation level, and the only piece of 'broken' machinery I had to adjust was replace `for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->elements[$i]->source->fields); $i++)` with `foreach ($this->elements[$i]->source->fields as $field)` and... voilá! ^_^